# unix bash - unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
maxDate='00000000'
fileDate='20140507'
if [[ $maxDate == '00000000' ]]; then   
  echo "right"
fi
echo $fileDate
```

This make me really crazy, I have spend whole day to deal with this format stuff.
the script is like above it print out unexpected end of file
if I delete the last line, it will not print anything which is not correct.
I really don't know what wrong with it.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Check your file with `cat --show-nonprinting filename`.

Comment: You probably have DOS line endings in your file. This means `then` is actually `then\r`, which `bash` does not recognize as terminating the command list which starts the `if` command, meaning the `bash` parser reaches the end of the file before ever finding the end of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the DOS line endings from your script with `dos2unix`. If that is not available, the following can be used:

```
tr -d '\r' < myscript > myscript.tmp
mv myscript.tmp myscript
```

Comment: I not fully understand what you mean, like my script file name is text, like you said, I typed tr -d '\r' < text > text.tmp mv text.tmp text. it is not work